# why emgu cv example didnt work?

Tags: c#, emgucv

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Copyright (C) 2004-2013 by EMGU. All rights reserved.       
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.VideoSurveillance;
using Emgu.Util;

namespace MotionDetection
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      private Capture _capture;
      private MotionHistory _motionHistory;
      private IBGFGDetector<Bgr> _forgroundDetector;

      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();

         //try to create the capture
         if (_capture == null)
         {
            try
            {
               _capture = new Capture();
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
            {   //show errors if there is any
               MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
            }
         }

         if (_capture != null) //if camera capture has been successfully created
         {
            _motionHistory = new MotionHistory(
                1.0, //in second, the duration of motion history you wants to keep
                0.05, //in second, maxDelta for cvCalcMotionGradient
                0.5); //in second, minDelta for cvCalcMotionGradient

            _capture.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;
            _capture.Start();
         }
      }

      private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         using (Image<Bgr, Byte> image = _capture.RetrieveBgrFrame())
         using (MemStorage storage = new MemStorage()) //create storage for motion components
         {
            if (_forgroundDetector == null)
            {
               //_forgroundDetector = new BGCodeBookModel<Bgr>();
               _forgroundDetector = new FGDetector<Bgr>(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FORGROUND_DETECTOR_TYPE.FGD);
               //_forgroundDetector = new BGStatModel<Bgr>(image, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.BG_STAT_TYPE.FGD_STAT_MODEL);
            }

            _forgroundDetector.Update(image);

            capturedImageBox.Image = image;

            //update the motion history
            _motionHistory.Update(_forgroundDetector.ForegroundMask);

            forgroundImageBox.Image = _forgroundDetector.ForegroundMask;

            #region get a copy of the motion mask and enhance its color
            double[] minValues, maxValues;
            Point[] minLoc, maxLoc;
            _motionHistory.Mask.MinMax(out minValues, out maxValues, out minLoc, out maxLoc);
            Image<Gray, Byte> motionMask = _motionHistory.Mask.Mul(255.0 / maxValues[0]);
            #endregion

            //create the motion image 
            Image<Bgr, Byte> motionImage = new Image<Bgr, byte>(motionMask.Size);
            //display the motion pixels in blue (first channel)
            motionImage[0] = motionMask;

            //Threshold to define a motion area, reduce the value to detect smaller motion
            double minArea = 100;

            storage.Clear(); //clear the storage
            Seq<MCvConnectedComp> motionComponents = _motionHistory.GetMotionComponents(storage);

            //iterate through each of the motion component
            foreach (MCvConnectedComp comp in motionComponents)
            {
               //reject the components that have small area;
               if (comp.area < minArea) continue;

               // find the angle and motion pixel count of the specific area
               double angle, motionPixelCount;
               _motionHistory.MotionInfo(comp.rect, out angle, out motionPixelCount);

               //reject the area that contains too few motion
               if (motionPixelCount < comp.area * 0.05) continue;

               //Draw each individual motion in red
               DrawMotion(motionImage, comp.rect, angle, new Bgr(Color.Red));
            }

            // find and draw the overall motion angle
            double overallAngle, overallMotionPixelCount;
            _motionHistory.MotionInfo(motionMask.ROI, out overallAngle, out overallMotionPixelCount);
            DrawMotion(motionImage, motionMask.ROI, overallAngle, new Bgr(Color.Green));

            //Display the amount of motions found on the current image
            UpdateText(String.Format("Total Motions found: {0}; Motion Pixel count: {1}", motionComponents.Total, overallMotionPixelCount));

            //Display the image of the motion
            motionImageBox.Image = motionImage;
         }
      }

      private void UpdateText(String text)
      {
         if (InvokeRequired && !IsDisposed)
         {
            Invoke((Action<String>)UpdateText, text);
         }
         else
         {
            label3.Text = text;
         }
      }

      private static void DrawMotion(Image<Bgr, Byte> image, Rectangle motionRegion, double angle, Bgr color)
      {
         float circleRadius = (motionRegion.Width + motionRegion.Height) >> 2;
         Point center = new Point(motionRegion.X + motionRegion.Width >> 1, motionRegion.Y + motionRegion.Height >> 1);

         CircleF circle = new CircleF(
            center,
            circleRadius);

         int xDirection = (int)(Math.Cos(angle * (Math.PI / 180.0)) * circleRadius);
         int yDirection = (int)(Math.Sin(angle * (Math.PI / 180.0)) * circleRadius);
         Point pointOnCircle = new Point(
             center.X + xDirection,
             center.Y - yDirection);
         LineSegment2D line = new LineSegment2D(center, pointOnCircle);

         image.Draw(circle, color, 1);
         image.Draw(line, color, 2);
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Clean up any resources being used.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
      protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
      {

         if (disposing && (components != null))
         {
            components.Dispose();
         }

         base.Dispose(disposing);
      }

      private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
      {
         _capture.Stop();
      }
   }
}
```

I have compiled emgu cv example

his name is **MotionDetection**

But when i compile that example, the result is error and he gives me message

**The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.**

i stuck on this `_capture = new Capture();`

I have add references to project
and i have copy opencv_core290.dll, opencv_highgui290.dll, and opencv_imgproc290.dll to project folder
but it still didnt work

the message still same
**The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.**

i use Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and Win 8.1
can anyone help me?

thanks :)

Comment: It'd be a shame if someone could answer this if there was code posted with the question.

Answer (score 0):

`The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception` means you need to look either in the static constructor of the class, or in the initialization of any static members of that class. I would, on top of that, take a look at  the `InnerException` property of where your exception is being thrown.

I'm willing to bet that you have static methods or elements that are being used incorrectly or illegally.

Take a gander here about the `TypeInitializationException`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typeinitializationexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: it from example

and i can't compile it

. Tutorial says just open example project and compile it
. It must works, 

but it didnt for me

Answer (score 0):

The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception its means that EMGU.CV file is not dectecting by code. this is due to system dependency. you need to go in to configration manger window in visual stdio and choose your required platform and then copy respective dll files(64 dll files forx64 and 32bit dll for x86 can be downloaded from emgu website ) according to your platform. copile it now there is no  error like emgu.cv.invoke